# Is it possible to overload geolocation functions using Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, geolocation, google-chrome-extension

I want to overload navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition and navigator.geolocation.watchPosition to simulate geolocation during
development. Is it possible to do it using Google Chrome extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition = function(successCallback, errorCallback) {
    successCallback({coords:{lattitude:10, longitude:20}});
}
```

If it is just for your own needs then it would be much easier to just do it in your js code.

If you want to make extension out of it then:

- This code needs to be injected on every page of your app (via content script) and put inside dynamically created `<script>` tag, otherwise you will be inside content script sandbox and your overwritten function will not be visible to the parent page.
- You would need to run this code before your app uses geolocation. There is no easy solution for this.

Comment: I think the solution for running the code before the app uses geolocation is to set "run_at" property to "document_start" in the manifest.json file.

Answer (score 1):

Now there's a chrome extension that does just that - the [manual geolocation](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mfodligkojepnddfhkbkodbamcagfhlo) chrome extension. It tries its best to inject the script before any other one.

Answer (score 0):

I found the extension what you want:)
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/change-geolocation/njjpmclekpigefnogajiknnheheacoaj